# Why is my page not rendering the data I need when trying to page redirect in jQuery/JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, page-refresh, window.location

The id's #switchtopagetwo and #switchtoindex are assigned to buttons that do what you can infer from the id's names. What I want to do is on click of the button, I want to redirect to the new page via window.location = url; and then run a function that renders some data on the page via pagetwoData() or pageoneData(), depending on where I am at the moment.

```
$('#switchtopagetwo').on('click', function () {
  window.location = 'pagetwo.html';
  pagetwoData();
});

//pagetwo.html button
$('#switchtoindex').on('click', function () {
  window.location = 'index.html';
  pageoneData();
});
```

When I comment out window.location, the functions run and I can see the data on the screen, but there's no page redirect even on clicking the button. When I click on the buttons fast enough, I can see the function's data being rendered for a split second and then disappearing. When I console.log certain items, I can see the console.log's appearing in the console and then disappearing the same way.

Clearly there is an issue with window.location. Is there better code I can use for clicking the button, redirecting the page to load the page-2 data, then clicking the button again to go back to page-1 data?

Answer (score 0):

When you redirect to a new page, the entire page context is abandoned and replaced by the new page.  Nothing which happens *on the source page* after that redirect can be relied upon to still happen.  But anything *on the target page* that's loading will happen.

Instead of trying to get Page1 to tell Page2 to do something when it loads, just have that something happen *on Page2*.  For example:

```
// on index.html
pageoneData();
$('#switchtopagetwo').on('click', function () {
    window.location = 'pagetwo.html';
});

// on pagetwo.html
pagetwoData();
$('#switchtoindex').on('click', function () {
    window.location = 'index.html';
});
```

Basically, for any given page, whatever you want to happen on that page when it loads should be executed on that page when it loads.